# const char pointer got Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Which are wrong（）?

```
(a)
const char * p = "apple"; 
p = "pig";

(b)
const char * p = "apple"; 
p[1] = 'x';

(c)
char * const p = "apple";
p = "pig";

(d)
char * const p = "apple";
p[1] = 'x';
```

---

I thing (b) and (c) are wrong.

(a) p: can change、const char:  can't change.

(b) p: can change、const char: can't change.

(c) const p: can't change、char: can change.

(d) const p: can't change、char: can change.

```
(a)
const char * p = "apple";    (O)
p = "pig";                // change pointer
    
(b)
const char * p = "apple";    (X)
p[1] = 'x';               // change value
    
(c)
char * const p = "apple";    (X)
p = "pig";                // change pointer
    
(d)
char * const p = "apple";    (O)
p[1] = 'x';               // change value
```

but when I using online complier to answer (d), I got the "Segmentation fault". I can't figure out what's going on.
[image]

Comment: Removed the c tag as it's a c++ question.

Comment: C++ should be learnt using a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by solving random online puzzles.